# What is the difference between Configuration vs ServiceRegistry vs StandardServiceRegistry?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate and I want to know if Configuration class is already there, then why we need ServiceRegistry and StandardServiceRegistry?

Why should I use ServiceRegistry and StandardServiceRegistry?

What are the advantages over Configuration class?

Should I use configuration class?

Answer (score 1):

These are two ways to bootstrap Hibernate: the `Configuration` is the [legacy way](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#appendix-legacy-bootstrap), while the `ServiceRegistry` way is the [recommended way](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap) starting Hibernate 5. Worth noting the following from the linked documentation:

> There are some significant drawbacks to the legacy bootstrapping mechanism which led to its deprecation and the development of the new approach, which is discussed in Native Bootstrapping.

> `Configuration` is semi-deprecated but still available for use, in a limited form that eliminates these drawbacks. "Under the covers", `Configuration` uses the new bootstrapping code, so the things available there are also available here in terms of auto-discovery.

As for the disadvantages, the best source is probably [this Jira issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2578) where they explain the rationale behind the redesign of the SessionFactory bootstrapping, which I believe mostly facilitates the ability to extend the framework.